# Zend_Form_Element_Select setValue is selecting more than one option

Tags: zend-framework, combobox, drop-down-menu, zend-form

I am using Zend 1.11.10 and I am trying to set a value in a dropdown list. My code is:

```
    $state = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("mytest");
    $state->setLabel("mytest")  
    ->setName("mytest");

    $state->addMultiOption('Pear','PE');
    $state->addMultiOption('Banana','BA');
    $state->addMultiOption('Orange','OR');
    $state->addMultiOption('Kiwi','KI');

    $state->setValue('Banana');

    $this->addElement($state);
```

The problem is that the generated HTML code is:

```
<select id="mytest" name="mytest" style="opacity: 0;"><option value="PE">Pear</option><option selected="selected" value="BA">Banana</option><option selected="selected" value="OR">Orange</option><option selected="selected" value="KI">Kiwi</option></select>
```

It is making "selected" all options after "Banana". Is this a bug in Zend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're using a non-standard `FormSelect` view helper. For starters, your `<option>` `value` attribute and text values are reversed and you have no `label` attributes. 
Eg, for

```
$state->addMultiOption('Pear','PE');
```

the generated markup should be

```
<option value="Pear" label="PE">PE</option>
```

I'd also hazard a guess that there's some JavaScript playing with the DOM due to the opacity style attribute.

Comment: There was a helper that was writing the HTML and causing this bug. So it is not a bug in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code exactly I get:

```
<select name="mytest" id="mytest"> 
    <option value="Pear" label="PE">PE</option> 
    <option value="Banana" label="BA" selected="selected">BA</option> 
    <option value="Orange" label="OR">OR</option> 
    <option value="Kiwi" label="KI">KI</option> 
</select>
```

this is also with 1.11.10. Are you using custom form classes or anything else that might be affecting it?